# Fetching data from JD Edwards Enterprise One to my PHP application using web services

Tags: php, oracle, web-services, jdedwards, enterpriseone

I have developed a custom web application in PHP. My client is using JD Edwards enterprise One 9.1, they need me to display the purchase orders and some of the stocks in the inventory in my application. I just need to pull data from the JD Edwards Enterprise One.

But, I am not able to find specific API or web services which can do that. So how can I accomplish this task? Any references?

Comment: Surely the JDE website will have details about this? What docs have you looked at? As it stands this question is very broad, and people can't know about the structure of the application in the way you do.

Comment: i want a list of standard business services that are offered by JDE. I want to list the purchase orders from JDE in to my application.

Answer (score 0):

EnterpriseOne 9.1 Bus Services are listed/described on the www.upgradejde.com website (via the Resources Tab, Technical Catalog (see left hand nav).  The site does require you to log in with your Oracle Account credentials.

Not sure if the link will work, but use the navigation described below if not.

[https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=50180:160:10431631993630::NO](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=50180:160:10431631993630%3a%3aNO):::